# Why is my JScrollpane not updating remove changes despite having validate() and repaint()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a terrible problem right now that's dooming my program at the moment. It seems that I can add elements to my ScrollPane via Jtable that has a custom model. It's fine when I add elements, the table updates and rows appear, etc etc. The real problem is when I remove elements it does not update the table no matter what. As a matter of fact, if I minimize the applet, then bring it up again, all the elements are now gone, but! the problem is that if I try to add new elements, they don't appear on ScrollPane even though the arraysize does grow when I add and shows my new elements when I println them. I've tried many things (you'll see with my repaints etc) but not sure what else i can do. thanks for any help :)

```
    modelx = new HumanListModel();
    final JTable newbiex = new JTable(modelx);  

    newbiex.setDefaultRenderer(Human.class, new HumanRenderer());
    newbiex.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    newbiex.setVisible(true);
    playerViewer.setViewportView(newbiex);


    removeIndividual.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {

            playerViewer.remove(newbiex.getSelectedRow());
            playerViewerExhibition.remove(newbiex.getSelectedRow());
            ///modelx.remove(newbiex.getSelectedRow());///

            modelx.removeElementAt(newbiex.getSelectedRow());

            indexPoint -= 1;///helps keep track of index///

            newbiex.repaint();
            newbiex.revalidate();
            newbiey.repaint(); ///table on another tab using modelx///
            newbiey.revalidate();///table on another tab///
            playerViewer.repaint();
            playerViewer.revalidate();
            System.out.println(modelx.size());

        }
    });
```

Comment: this is NOT a `SSCCE`. How can we compile and execute this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
modelx.removeElementAt(newbiex.getSelectedRow());
```

The TableModel doesn't have a method by this name so you must be creating a custom method. Make sure this method invokes `fireTableRowsDeleted(...)`. You can always look at the source code of the DefaultTableModel to see how this is done.

```
newbiex.repaint();
newbiex.revalidate();
newbiey.repaint(); ///table on another tab using modelx///
newbiey.revalidate();///table on another tab///
playerViewer.repaint();
playerViewer.revalidate();
```

None of the above code is needed. If you fire the appropriate events from the model the table will automatically repaint itself.

> if I minimize the applet, then bring it up again, all the elements are now gone, but! the problem is that if I try to add new elements, they don't appear on ScrollPane even though the arraysize does grow when I add and shows my new elements when I println them. I've tried many things (you'll see with my repaints etc) but not sure what else i can do. thanks for any help :)

I would say you have implemented your TableModel incorrectly. Try using the `DefaultTableModel`. It supports dynamic addition/removal of rows.

Or you can check out [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). You would only need to implement a couple of methods. The JButtonTableModel gives a simple example of how to do this.

Comment: Are you saying instead of HumanListModel to use DefaultTableModel?

Comment: I don't know what your data is like. Many times you can just use the DefaultTableMdoel. Otherwise, I'm suggesting you have implement your HumanListModel incorrectly. So you need to fix the problems. I also suggested that instead of creating a model from scratch you could use the RowTableModol and just implement a few methods. The RowTableModel also supports dynamic addition/removal of rows. Whatever you decide, you need to understand how to use TableModels better.

Comment: Thanks camickr I'll take your advice, @mKrobel, I've read the SSCCE, what did I do wrong with my original post, not sure why it's not SSCCE and i have read SSCCE actually...

Comment: I'm trying to use ListTableModel, however, they don't seem to have a getSelectedRow() method which I need since it's depend on me highlighting an item and adding to another table...

Comment: The TableModel has nothing to do with row selection. JTable already supports row selection when the user clicks on a row. If you want to manually select rows then see JTable.getSelectionModel() and make your changes to ListSelectionModel. The table also has methods to return the currently selected index. Read the API.

Comment: Yea I''m reading it. I decided to use the Rowtablemodel and listablemodel but changing it to work with human objects, human is my custom class

Comment: You just need to use the `RowTableModel` with your `Human` class. Look at the `JButtonTableModel` to get an example of how you can extend RowTableModel to work with your Human class.

Comment: Hi, I made an arraylist of the class that I created, in this case human, but how do I get the arraylist to be displayed using ListTableModel. Also, my custom class has an getAge() method but how do I get the listTableModel to extract this method from the added object to be displayed in the "Age" column? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I already stated you don't use the ListTableModel. You extend the RowTableModel. The JButtonTableModel is a working example of how this might be done.

Comment: Ok, I have one last question because I'm trying to understand the different between tablemodels and listmodels. Can you explain that a bit? Thanks!

Comment: A TableModel us used by a JTable. A ListModel is used by a JList. Each Swing component has its own model, although text components call it a Document.

Comment: I don't get it Camickr, I'm using ListModel becuase it extends RowTable. And I'm stuck on creating a RowTableModel I can't even initialize a new one, I've been trying various things but just can't create it. I know this may seem completely silly but I'm not that experienced. I tried something like this: RowTableModel rModel = new RowTableModel(humanList, stringList); Tried other things, nothing seems to work, I took a close look at the class but can't get anything to work :(

Comment: I don't know what to say. You should not be looking at the RowModel class because you don't change that class. You can't create a RowTableModel directly. You need to extend RowTableModel and implement a couple of methods. I suggested you look at the `JButtonTableModel` example code because it is a working example.

Answer (score -1):

It's a common problem in JTable, I usually reset the visibility after all the codes executed.

`JTable.setVisible(false);`
`JTable.setVisible(true);`

It works for me..

Comment: -1, there is no need to do anything like that. A JTable automatically repaints itself when you update the TableModel. You must make sure your TableModel fires the appropriate events.

Comment: I wish it worked for me :( I tried it I think the problem is more fundamental because after I delete just 2 elements from the row, the column name also deletes itself. To be more detailed, after I delete the first item, the scrollpane bar disappears too lol.  I'm thoroughly baffled.